# Syntax Error received on If statement line

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am receiving an error in the editor (and again in the console after running a py file, described in the console as a SyntaxError) on a line that includes an If statement

The code below is included in the file

```
if a = 4:
    b = 1
if a = 4:
    b = 1
if a = 4:
    b = 1
```

the code itself is redundant, but the error is only showing up (in the editor) on the first If line and not the others.  What would be causing this error on only the first line of code when the others are identical?

Comment: You need two equal signs. `if a == 4:`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the programming language you are using (I guess it's python?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [if](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp) statement evaluates a boolean expression. `if a = 4` is not a boolean expression in python. You have to use the `==` symbol.
Try this:

```
if a == 4:
    b = 1
if a == 4:
    b = 1
if a == 4:
    b = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparison for equality is done using the == operator (you're using a single = which is for assignments only). Also, you're missing a colon:

```
if result == "PASS":
```